# Indirect function call uses odd address

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m

When the GCC 4.7.3 (20121207) for ARM Cortex-M3 takes the address of a function it doesn't get the exact address of the function. I can see an off-by-one in that pointer.

```
// assume at address 0x00001204;
int foo() {
  return 42;
}

void bar() {
  int(*p)() = &foo;  // p = 0x1205;
  p();               // executed successfully
  foo();             // assembly: "bl 0x00001204;"
}
```

Although the pointer points to an odd address, the execution is successful. I would expect an exception at this point. Why does it takes that strange address and why doesn't it hurt.

**Edit**

- The [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120711/linux-kernel-why-a-functions-address-in-system-map-is-one-byte-before-its-add) describes a difference between thumb and ARM mode. Why is that offset not visible when the function is called directly although the CPU is in the same mode?
- Should the odd address be kept or would resetting the bit 0  cause hard? (what I could not see until now)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong method implementation address from otool for armv7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045144/wrong-method-implementation-address-from-otool-for-armv7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux Kernel - why a function's address in System.map is one byte before its address as seen in real time? e.g. in a printk output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120711/linux-kernel-why-a-functions-address-in-system-map-is-one-byte-before-its-add)

Comment: The cortex-m3 is a thumb/thumb2 only machine.  Thumb function addresses are generally odd to indicate that it is a thumb function/address not an arm address (which is always even and moreso even and a power of 4).  I suspect that is what you are seeing.

Comment: @dwelch Thanks for reply. Why does this is not visible in the disassembled code? I see here even addresses.

Comment: it depends on the code, I can give you some examples.  bx/blx need an odd address bl does not because it does not change modes, when you bl to something it can/will use the even address, when you ask for the address of a thumb function you will get the odd version

Comment: @dwelch since it is thumb only, isn't there a chance that bit is omitted in the core always (hardwired), meaning it wouldn't make a difference even with bx/blx?

Comment: you would think/hope, but I am pretty sure that the cortex-m generates an exeception, probably a prefetch abort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cobbled up something from one of my examples to quickly demonstrate what is going on.

`vectors.s`:

```
/* vectors.s */
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

.word   0x20002000  /* stack top address */
.word   _start      /* 1 Reset */
.word   hang        /* 2 NMI */
.word   hello       /* 3 HardFault */
.word   hang        /* 4 MemManage */
.word   hang        /* 5 BusFault */
.word   hang        /* 6 UsageFault */
.word   hang        /* 7 RESERVED */
.word   hang        /* 8 RESERVED */
.word   hang        /* 9 RESERVED*/
.word   hang        /* 10 RESERVED */
.word   hang        /* 11 SVCall */
.word   hang        /* 12 Debug Monitor */
.word   hang        /* 13 RESERVED */
.word   hang        /* 14 PendSV */
.word   hang        /* 15 SysTick */
.word   hang        /* 16 External Interrupt(0) */
.word   hang        /* 17 External Interrupt(1) */
.word   hang        /* 18 External Interrupt(2) */
.word   hang        /* 19 ...   */

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
    /*ldr r0,stacktop */
    /*mov sp,r0*/
    bl notmain
    ldr r0,=notmain
    mov lr,pc
    bx r0
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .

hello: b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.end
```

`blinker01.c`:

```
extern void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );

int notmain ( void )
{
    PUT32(0x12345678,0xAABBCCDD);
    return(0);
}
```

Makefile:

```
#ARMGNU = arm-none-eabi
ARMGNU = arm-none-linux-gnueabi

AOPS = --warn --fatal-warnings 
COPS = -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding 


all : blinker01.gcc.thumb.bin 

vectors.o : vectors.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as vectors.s -o vectors.o

blinker01.gcc.thumb.o : blinker01.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -mthumb -c blinker01.c -o blinker01.gcc.thumb.o

blinker01.gcc.thumb2.o : blinker01.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -march=armv7-m -c blinker01.c -o blinker01.gcc.thumb2.o

blinker01.gcc.thumb.bin : memmap vectors.o blinker01.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o blinker01.gcc.thumb.elf -T memmap vectors.o blinker01.gcc.thumb.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D blinker01.gcc.thumb.elf > blinker01.gcc.thumb.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy blinker01.gcc.thumb.elf blinker01.gcc.thumb.bin -O binary
```

Disassembly:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start-0x50>:
 8000000:   20002000    andcs   r2, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000051    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r4, r6}
 8000008:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 800000c:   0800005e    stmdaeq r0, {r1, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000010:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000014:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000018:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 800001c:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000020:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000024:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000028:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 800002c:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000030:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000034:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000038:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 800003c:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000040:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000044:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 8000048:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}
 800004c:   0800005d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3, r4, r6}

08000050 <_start>:
 8000050:   f000 f80a   bl  8000068 <notmain>
 8000054:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (8000064 <PUT32+0x4>)
 8000056:   46fe        mov lr, pc
 8000058:   4700        bx  r0
 800005a:   e7ff        b.n 800005c <hang>

0800005c <hang>:
 800005c:   e7fe        b.n 800005c <hang>

0800005e <hello>:
 800005e:   e7fe        b.n 800005e <hello>

08000060 <PUT32>:
 8000060:   6001        str r1, [r0, #0]
 8000062:   4770        bx  lr
 8000064:   08000069    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3, r5, r6}

08000068 <notmain>:
 8000068:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
 800006a:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (8000078 <notmain+0x10>)
 800006c:   4903        ldr r1, [pc, #12]   ; (800007c <notmain+0x14>)
 800006e:   f7ff fff7   bl  8000060 <PUT32>
 8000072:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000074:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
 8000076:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000078:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
 800007c:   aabbccdd    bge 6ef33f8 <_start-0x110cc58>
```

First off note `hang` vs `hello`, this is a gnuism you need to, in assembly, declare a label to be a thumb function in order for it to actually work for this kind of thing.  `hang` is properly declared and the vector table properly uses the odd address, `hello` is not properly declared and the even address is put in there. C compiled code automatically does this properly.

Here is a prime example of what you are asking though, `bl` to the C function `notmain` does not, cannot, use an odd address.  But to use `bx` you ask for the address to the function `main` and that address is provided to the code as 0x8000069 for for a function at address 0x8000068, if you did a `bx` to 0x800068 on an ARMvsometingT it would switch to arm mode and crash eventually if it hit thumb mode (hopefully crash and not stumble along) on a cortex-m a `bx` to an even address should fault immediately.

```
08000050 <_start>:
 8000050:   f000 f80a   bl  8000068 <notmain>
 8000054:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (8000064 <PUT32+0x4>)
 8000056:   46fe        mov lr, pc
 8000058:   4700        bx  r0
 800005a:   e7ff        b.n 800005c <hang>
 8000064:   08000069    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3, r5, r6}
```

Why can't `bl` be odd?  Look at the encoding  above `bl` from 0x8000050 to 0x8000068, the `pc` is two ahead so 4 byte so take 0x8000068 - 0x8000054 = 0x14 divide that by 2 and you get 0x00A. That is the offset to the `pc` and that is what is encoded in the instructions (the 0A in the second half of the instruction).  The divide by two is based on knowledge that thumb instructions are always 2 bytes (well at the time) and so they can reach twice as far if they put the offset in 2 byte instructions rather than in bytes. So the `lsbit` is lost of the delta between the two, so controlled by the hardware.

What your code did was in one place you asked for the address of a thumb function which gives the odd address, the other case was looking at the disassembly of a branch link which is always even.

Comment: The description how the even address in disassembly became even address is very comprehensive.